# PHP Myadmin types

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have 4 columns in my phpmyadmin database but I don't know what to save `id, username,pw, email` as . Can someone help me with what type to put these columns as ? All what is the max . Thanks .

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` = A tool written in PHP to help you Admin a MYSQL database. `MYSQL` is a database `phpMyAdmin` is not a database

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/PHP-MySQL-Dummies-Janet-Valade/dp/0470527587

Comment: Ok . Can you help with my question ?

Comment: http://www.elated.com/articles/mysql-for-absolute-beginners/

Comment: that doesn't say what I should save my columns as

Comment: **Do not** save actual passwords. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), **`password_hash`/`password_verify`**, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: @mkd Yes, because it's assumed you'll use your brain. You need to consider what the data needs and pick a column type. Don't use `TINYINT` for an email address. Don't use `LONGTEXT` for a user ID. The choices are generally quite obvious after a few minutes in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `id` use `AUTO_INCREMENT`, though that's not a data type but it will automatically use `int`

`username` use `VARCHAR` and then you can set the maximum length of characters that the username can be

`password` use `VARCHAR`, if you're hashing the password then make sure you set enough length that can take the hashed text

`email` should also be `VARCHAR`

Check [mysql datatype documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) for more information

Comment: Use 255 as the max. By the time you need to optimize your db you will know enough to choose a more appropriate value.

Comment: If the OP is encrypting the password that is wrong and not secure. This is PHP, passwords should be handled with `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: @zaph, `password_hash()` returns a string, how is it improper to store that in a varchar column?

Comment: The issue is the answer states "encrypting the password", `password_hash` is not encryption, hashing and encryption are two different things.

Comment: Thanks @zaph I had to make a little research and now I've gotten your point. I've edited the answer to address the issue

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and even adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Please use secure password methods.

Answer (score 0):

If this is users table check this

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   username VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE,
   email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
   password VARCHAR(255) //If want hashing
);
```

`MAX` is the maximum value a datatype can save.